# List index out of range while parsing through f

Tags: python

When I run this code

```py
for line in file:
    splitline = line.rsplit()
    print(splitline)
```

I get

```py
['51559', 'Zhovti', 'Vody,', 'Ukraine']
['51543', 'Minokamo,', 'Japan']
['51541', 'Takāb,', 'Iran']
['51534', 'Tucupita,', 'Venezuela']
['51526', 'Emden,', 'Germany']
['51519', 'Amparafaravola,', 'Madagascar']
['51508', 'Saginaw,', 'Michigan,', 'United', 'States']
['51498', 'Talā,', 'Egypt']
```

However whenever I try to retrieve only the 2nd element in each line,

```py
for line in file:
    splitline = line.rsplit()
    print(splitline[1])
```

I get this: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Most probably in your file there is one line which is having just one word.

Comment: You can use try except also to get exact line where you are having just one element in splitline variable

Comment: What format has `file`?

Comment: @Thomas It is a txt file

Comment: @raviraj You were right! The first line of this code was creating the problem. Is there anyway to ignore this first line without deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **try except** to handle the error as below. As you are getting `IndexError` you can handle it below.

```
for line in file:
    splitline = line.rsplit()
    try:
        print(splitline[1])
    except IndexError:
        print("please check index")
```

Comment: Blindly catching all exceptions with `except:` is dangerous as it will catch everything, including out of memory errors or keyboard interrupts (no more ctrl+c to stop your program). It would be much better to only catch the specific IndexError.

Comment: @LukeNelson thought of it first place only but do not exactly what he is trying to do so wrote basic code for him. Anyway we should always follow good coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

A little error checking should solve this problem.  For example, one possible solution is:

```
for line in file:
    if line:
        splitline = line.rsplit()
        if splitline and len(splitline) > 1:
            print(splitline[1])
```

In the alternative, you could use try-except blocks. Some people in Python practice the "ask forgiveness, not permission" approach, which means try to do what you want, and catch an exception in case of failure. Others believe in the "do thorough error-checking at each stage" approach.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fact that we are trying to get an value from an index that doesn't exist. In my situation, the first line of the code was the issue, so I simply just used file.readline() to get past the first value.

Comment: So does this mean that you just blindly read and throw away the first line? That may work for this particular scenario, but in general it's better practice to check each line and handle it accordingly.  Something as simple as 'for line in file: if line:' is an improvement. It's best to handle possible variations in input as generally as possible.

Comment: @Gary02127 I agree with you but the solution to this problem includes that because it's a problem with the txt file itself.